# Synchronize application.properties when deploying in kubernetes

Tags: git, spring-boot, kubernetes, application.properties, configmap

I would like to know what is the best practice of synchronizing our application.properties in our deployment in kubernetes with our git repository. Every time there is a change in application.properties in our git repo, we need to manually update also the application.properties inside the kubernetes deployment. Is there are way that when we restart the application it checks the git repo if there is a change then it automatically updates the application.properties in kubernetes too.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would have a step in your CI script or config that syncs the new config into a ConfigMap or something. Though if this is something more like code than config, maybe it should live in the container image instead?